# Abstract Jordan decomposition maybe not exist

Tags: lie-algebras

An *abstract Jordan decomposition* of an element of a Lie algebra L is a decomposition
of the form a = a$_{s}$ + a$_{n}$, where

(a) ad a$_{s}$ is a diagonalizable (equivalently semisimple) endomorphism of L.

(b) ad a$_{n}$ is a nilpotent endomorphism.

(c) [a$_{s}$, a$_{n}$] = 0 .

[This note](http://math.mit.edu/classes/18.745/Notes/Lecture_12_Notes.pdf) defines the abstract Jordan decomposition in an arbitrary Lie algebra. Abstract Jordan decomposition in a Lie algebra is unique **when it exists** iff its centre is zero. It seems that the abstract Jordan decomposition maybe not exist even when its centre is zero, who can show me an example?

The same question is at [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3406659/abstract-jordan-decomposition-maybe-not-exist) with no answer.

Comment: it is better if you define what abstract Jordan decomposition is. The note you have referred to talks about Jordan decomposition in complex semi simple Lie algebras

Comment: OK, I rewrite the definition 12.1 in the note.

Comment: 野蛮啃老怪死装大概好像是死了，，，

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In $\mathfrak g=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}x&x&y\\0&x&z\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}:x,y,z\in \mathbf R\right\}$, $\mathrm{ad}$-semisimple and $\mathrm{ad}$-nilpotent elements all have $x=0$; so they don’t span.

Comment: About the ad-semisimple case, choose the basis e$_{11}$+e$_{12}$+e$_{22}$,e$_{13}$ and e$_{23}$？

Comment: @Strongart Well, take any basis (that doesn’t affect diagonalizability and nilpotency), but yes, using this one, the above matrix $a$ has $$\mathrm{ad}(a)=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\-y-z&x&x\\-z&0&x\end{pmatrix}$$ which is nilpotent iff $x=0$, and *not* semisimple if $x\ne0$: $\det(\lambda I-\mathrm{ad}(a))=\lambda(\lambda -x)^2$, and eigenvalue $x$ has only a 1-dimensional eigenspace ($\mathbf Re_{13}$).

Comment: I see, even when x = 0, it is also not ad-semisimple, it has no ad-semisimple part.